# Finitely generated semisimple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is it true that  a finitely generated semisimple module $M$  a finite direct sum of simple submodules? Is it why a finitely generated semisimple module has finite uniform dimension?

I know that a semisimple module is a direct sum of simple (hence, uniform) modules. So, if the first question has positive answer, then any f. g. semisimple module would have u. dim=the number of the components in the direct summand.

Comment: An infinite direct sum of nonzero modules is not finitely generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it true that a finitely generated semisimple module M is a finite direct sum of simple submodules?

Of course it is. If $M$ is semisimple and f.g., the generators all lie inside a finite subset of the summands, and so their span lies there too.

> Is it why a finitely generated semisimple module has finite uniform dimension?

Yes,  you can conclude that.